# Merge multiple calls preserving order

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to combine 5 network calls to get a list of objects needed then to be displayed in a separate lists on the UI:

- Apples
- Bananas
- Oranges
- Kiwis
- Pears

Followed some tutorials over the web, I'm creating 5 `Observables` and merging their emissions afterwards:

```
Observable<FruitResponse> apples=
                _fruits.getApples(store_id)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
...
Observable<FruitResponse> pears =
                _fruits.getPears(store_id)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

 List<Observable<FruitResponse>> observables = new ArrayList();
        observables.add(apples);
        observables.add(bananas);
        observables.add(oranges);
        observables.add(kiwis);
        observables.add(pears);

        Observable
                .merge(observables)
                .toList()
                .single()
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<FruitResponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<FruitResponse> list) {

                        ArrayList<Fruit> fruit_list = new ArrayList<Fruits>();
                        for (FruitResponse f : list) {
                           fruit_list.get(0).getName()); // -- always different
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The problem is that the order of objects emitted is different every time the code is executed and I need to get a list in a specific order described above, thus I'll know what each object is related to (list of apples  or bananas or etc.) and be able to push it to the `Adapter` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat()` instead of `merge()`

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html